L'espressione "nei ripari"
Nella traduzione di un poema di Puškin da Tommaso Landolfi, abbiamo:

Amo il fastoso appassimento della natura,
I boschi vestiti di porpora e d’oro,
Nei loro ripari il rombo e il fresco spirare del vento,

Sarà che "Nei loro ripari" = "Al loro riparo"? Ho già sentito "al riparo" ma mai "nei ripari".
edit: Aggiungo l'originale russo:

Люблю я пышное природы увяданье,
В багрец и в золото одетые леса,
В их сенях ветра шум и свежее дыханье,

Neanche il russo è la mia madrelingua (di solito, capisco meglio l'italiano). Qui ho un problema con l'espressione "В их сенях" (tradotta come "Nei loro ripari"). Mi pare che l'espressione "под сенью" si può tradurre come "al riparo" (che, secondo me, farebbe senso qui), invece ho visto che "В сенях" si  può tradurre più o meno come "all'entrata" (vedete qui) (sembra strano qui, quindi probabilmente ha diversi sensi quest'espressione, ho fatto la domanda su Russian Language Stackexchange). (Per chi non può leggere il russo, "их" = "loro".) Qui una traduzione in inglese:

I love the sumptuous glow of fading nature,
the forests clad in crimson and in gold,
the shady coolness and the wind's dull roaring,


It could help to see the same poem translation to other languages, like English or Spanish, to better grasp what the author intended to say. Can you [edit] and add those info?

O magari l'originale russo. Comunque, a prescindere dall'originale, “nei loro ripari” non mi suona particolarmente strano. La parola “riparo” è un normale sostantivo della lingua italiana e quindi lo si può usare in una qualsiasi frase, come se avesse detto “nei loro anfratti”, “nei loro rifugi” etc.

Se l'espressione ha senso per un madrelingua, potresti scriverla come risposta, vero?

Confermo quello che dice DaG, l'espressione 'nei loro ripari' non ha nulla di strano, né mi suona nuova, è caso mai più poetica di 'al riparo, che suonerebbe più quotidiana.

Ad esempio Eugenio Montale: l’orto assetato sporge irti ramelli
oltre i chiusi ripari (da Il canneto rispunta i suoi cimelli, Ossi di seppia)

Di chi sono i ripari? Dei boschi («леса»). Nell'originale «сень» è al prepositivo plurale, da cui la traduzione plurale in italiano. In italiano dà la sensazione che questi luoghi riparati sotto il fogliame siano molteplici e sparpagliati, che forse è il motivo del plurale anche in russo. Non ha un suono insolito, sicuramente non in un poesia comunque.
La traduzione inglese è meno fedele, e se la cava con «shady».

Nella poesia di Montale che ho citato sopra, nella versione su internet che ho linkato c'è un errore nel nono verso. Il verso dice come manchi in questa plaga* e non come manchi di questa plaga. Mi suonava strano e ho controllato, sulla edizione storica de 'I poeti dello Specchio' di Mondadori.

Ottima la citazione montaliana, @BakerStreet! Se come mi sembra concordi con la mia opinione, ti va di scrivere una risposta in cui dai anche l'esempio di quei versi?

Grazie @DaG. Io non ho proprio il tempo, se vuoi puoi rispondere tu, cita quello che vuoi dai miei commenti, Montale non è mia proprietà! Se non puoi e non può qualcun altro, posso scriverla, ma tra qualche giorno.

Come vedi, l'ho fatto, @BakerStreet . Ovviamente, se credi, modifica o integra pure.

Grazie, @DaG, ottimo! Se avrò il tempo vorrei cercare qualche altra occorrenza, ma è perfetto così.

Nel testo originale russo si usa la parola сень che ha almeno quattro significati diversi, parti di una catena dello sviluppo metonimico: "ombra" > "area coperta o sovrastata da qualcosa" > "copertura, dominante" > "chioma, corona (di un albero)". E' una sfida distinguere fra tutti questi significati anche per i russoparlanti. Ma nel testo russo si tratta inequivocabilmente dell'ultimo significato, cioè "chiome (degli alberi) del bosco".
"Riparo" è abbastanza simile ad "area coperta" perchè il traduttore scelga il significato sbagliato, e molti potrebbero fare lo stesso errore. Potrebbe anche essere che il traduttore abbia scelto il significato non preciso per ragioni poetiche.
Detto questo, non mi sembra che "nei loro ripari" vada bene senza riguardo al testo russo.
Primo, l'espressione "nei ripari", di per sè, è corretta e si usa spesso:


Le crisalidi si possono ricercare, sugli alberi, nei ripari di foglie
Indi, assaliti nel medesimo tempo da tutte le parti i pirati ed inseguitili nei loro ripari di Cilicia, in tre mesi li distrusse e rese la sicurezza al mare


Ma non mi sembra che i due sensi di "nei ripari" siano interscambiabili. Nel primo estratto, "nei ripari di foglie" si usa nel senso metaforico. Non si tratta di un luogo fisico, e si può sostituire con "protette da foglie". Nel secondo estratto, "nei loro ripari" si usa nel senso diretto: ci furono delle grotte o qualcosa del genere in Cilicia, dove i pirati si nascosero. Nella traduzione di Landolfi, questi due significati mi sembrano confusi: parla di "ripari dei boschi" come se fossero i luoghi fisici. Però non sono madrelingua, quindi potrei sbagliarmi.
Secondo, Puškin è ben noto per usare le immagini molto precise nelle sue fatiche sia di prosa che di poesia. Le chiome degli alberi sono proprio dove si fa il rumore del vento, dunque mi sembra che "nelle loro chiome" sarebbe una scelta più naturale, per mantenere la precisone dell'imagine originale, se non altro.

Grazie per il chiaromento del testo russo. Però si tratta di una traduzione di un poeta fatta da un poeta, e in genere  le traduzioni delle poesie non sono  necessariamente letterali, si privilegia la resa poetica complessiva,  la fedeltà complessiva alla poesia,  alla fedeltà  parola per parola, che produce una brutta poesia.  D'altra parte, trasformare, per essere letterali, una poesia magnifica in una brutta è il peggior tradimento!

Le traduzioni di poesia fatte da poeti sono inoltre da questi concepite quasi come loro produzione poetica, è impensabile che si mettano  a fare cose brutte per essere letterali. 'Nei ripari' è normalissimo in poesia, 'nel riparo' sarebbe suonato prosaico, brutto, inadatto al tono alto del poema. Purtroppo la traduzione della poesia è una cosa difficilissima, al limite dell'impossibilità.

Tieni presente che quando un italiano si dedica a tradurre letteratura russa, lo fa quasi con reverenza, e non lo fa chiunque, chi lo fa è un vero esperto e sa di avere un compito alto. C'è una grande ammirazione per la letteratura russa. Io la considero, forse, la più grande dell'ottocento. Per cui escluderei l'ipotesi di errori o sciatterie di traduzione.

Questa risposta è interessantissima ma, per così dire, fuori tema. Dato che la domanda e questo StackExchange sono sulla lingua italiana, qui è in questione solo se in italiano si possa dire “nei loro ripari” e con quale significato. Conoscere oli senso dell'originale russo è utile, ma di per sé non dà una risposta sul testo italiano.

@BakerStreet In generale le traduzioni da T. L. sono molto letterali (ogni verso corresponde a un verso, lui cambia l'ordine delle parole perché in russo l'ordine è meno stretto che in italiano) (e non "brute" affatto): "Essendomi io, cioè, proposto dapprima di tradurre questa poesia secondo un criterio di puntigliosa trasposizione verbale, ben presto dovetti convincermi esser quella maniera più sicura per tradirla..." (T. L.)

Sono stato incomodato con "nei loro ripari" nel contesto (per questo la mia domanda). La risposta di Quassnoi mi convince: T. L. ha capito male qui (uno dei rarissimi casi - anch’io avevo capito male il russo qui ma mi capita molto più spesso!) ma prova a continuare a tradurre letteralmente: в -> nei, их -> loro, сенях -> "ripari" invece di "chiome" (avessi letto « nelle loro chiome » non sarei stato incomodato).

Non capisco cosa capiscono quelli che non sono incomodati da « nei loro ripari ». I "ripari" sono i boschi stessi? Questo potrebbe fare senso; avrei piuttosto scritto "al loro riparo" o "in questi ripari", ma forse "nei loro ripari" ha anche questo senso - la risposta di DaG sembra dire che « nei loro ripari » può avere questo senso ma non sono sicuro? Oppure capiscono che questi « ripari » sono dei ripari che pertengono ai boschi (questa sembra l’interpretazione di @MauroVanetti - fa senso che i ripari siano i fogliami ma avrei aspettato una descrizione più explicita da Puškin)?

Non conosco il russo, quindi non so giudicare la letteralità della traduzione, né i motivi della scelta di Landolfi. Ma mi semba che si sta facendo una questione troppo complicata di una scelta terminologic che in italiano appare molto naturale, il senso in italiano è chiarissimo, gli alberi fanno da riparo con le loro chiome.

Sulla scelta del termine 'ripari' c'è poco da dire se non cose soggettive,. A me 'chiome' sarebbe sembrato orribile, una parola troppo prosaica per il contesto, peggio di 'al riparo' al singolare, sembra una traduzione fatta da un bambino i dodici anni che vuole parlare raffinato, ha un sentore di poesia scadente. Questo è quello che mi sembra da quel po' di orecchio che mi sono fatto nel tempo leggendo poesia italiana, ma sono cose soggettive e io non è che faccio testo.

@Bruno Hai scritto: "Non capisco cosa capiscono quelli che non sono incomodati da « nei loro ripari ». I "ripari" sono i boschi stessi? Questo potrebbe fare senso; avrei piuttosto scritto "al loro riparo" o "in questi ripari". Non c'è nessuna ambiguità, non c'è molto da capire, riparafrasando: i boschi creano dei ripari, dei luoghi riparati,   con le loro chiome, il loro fogliame, essi stessi complessivamente, comunque lo si voglia dire.

@Bruno Condivido ogni parola di quello che dice BakerStreet qui sopra, e non capisco proprio perché “nei ripari” dovrebbe “incomodare” qualcuno: sono due normalissime parole della lingua italiana.

Un' ultima osservazione, riguardo a questa  interessante risposta di @Quassnoi. Negli esempi che fai in italiano, i ripari di foglie delle crisalidi, i ripari dei pirati in Cilicia, i ripari dei boschi in Landolfi, sono tutti luoghi fisici, significa luoghi riparati, se uno sta sotto gli alberi in un bosco  sta 'nei ripari dei boschi', materialmente, non sono metafore.

A prescindere dall'originale, “nei loro ripari” non suona particolarmente strano. La parola “riparo” è un normale sostantivo della lingua italiana e quindi lo si può usare in una qualsiasi frase, come se si fosse detto “nei loro anfratti”, “nei loro rifugi” etc. Quindi “nei loro ripari” è una semplice espressione italiana e, semmai, più poetica  e meno quotidiana di “al riparo”
Come controprova, troviamo un'espressione simile in Eugenio Montale:

l’orto assetato sporge irti ramelli
oltre i chiusi ripari, all'afa stagna

(da “Il canneto rispunta i suoi cimelli...”, in Ossi di seppia).
